# Can a MySQL query summarize time+user data into a time x user report?

Tags: mysql, sql, multidimensional-array, report, pivot

I have a MySQL table with the following schema that records user activity:

```
TABLE Activity:
id      INT AUTOINCREMENT  // the primary key
ts      TIMESTAMP          // similar to DATETIME
user    INT                // a unique ID for each user
action  INT                // action code
```

Each time a user does an action, a row is added to this table. What I want to do now is generate a report summarizing total user activity per day. It would, for instance, look something like this:

```
Date       | User 1 | User 2 | User 3
--------------------------------------
2013-03-05 |     12 |     34 |     56
2013-03-06 |     78 |     87 |     65
2013-03-07 |     43 |     21 |     12
```

In this example, user 1 did 78 actions on March 6, and 43 actions on March 7, and user 3 did 56 actions on March 5. At this point I don't care what kind of actions were done on a particular day, just the total number of all actions that were done by a particular user.

Now writing a MySQL query to summarize entries in the activity table into days for a single user is relatively straightforward, and I could run such a query for each user in turn (though the days columns in each result set might not align perfectly). Is there a way to do this for all users automatically in one query?

I think this might be a little weird because the number of columns in the result could vary depending on how many users were active in the date range of interest. In other words, the number of columns in the report might be less than the number of users in the database.

Essentially, rather than having MySQL generate a one-dimensional array of records as its output, I want it to generate a two-dimensional array of values, where the labels for the rows and columns are derived from the activity table. Is this even possible?

I suppose I could always just go through the raw data in the table and build up a proper two dimensional array myself (I'll be working in PHP), but I was wondering if MySQL could do that for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivoting (technical term for what you're trying to do) is usually not worth the trouble.  If you only needed to get data for a few users, it would be fine, but if you need to be able to get data for a dynamic list of users, you're better off doing  a single query grouped by `ts` and `user` like this

```sql
SELECT DATE(`ts`) AS `Date`, `User`, COUNT(*) AS `Actions`
FROM `Activity`
#WHERE (conditions)
GROUP BY `Date`, `User`
```

and making a multidimensional array out of that in PHP like this:

```php
$result; // result from DB call as an array of objects
$user_actions = array();
foreach($result as $row){
    $user_actions[$row->Date][$row->User] = $row->Actions;
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, @G-Nugget. +1 for the simple solution and for telling me about the term "pivot". Knowing the right terminology makes such a difference. :)